# Listings and Float package ordering cause \parskip to be ignored in list of listings \lstlistoflistings

Tags: listings, packages, parskip

## Ordering matters with `listings` and `float` packages else `\parskip` is ignored

I was trying to figure out why in my list of listings (`\lstlistoflistings`) the `\parskip` was being ignored, when eventually I narrowed it down to the `listings` package not cooperating with the `float` package, and something being ordering specific.

## When `float` is first something goes wrong

If I use this (which initially I did as I try to organise packages alphabetically where possible).

```latex
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{listings}
```

then the `\parskip` gets ignored in the list of listings but respected in the other lists, as can be seen below:

[image]

[image]

If I ensure `listings` is loaded before `float` then everything works fine. I am not familiar with inspecting the internals of packages and don't know what's going wrong, and which package is at fault (if either).

- What's going wrong under the hood?
- Who's at fault? (Where to report the bug if it's a bug?).

## MWE

Fairly minimal but with a few items of each to show the spacing, and a comprehensive set of lists of, showing that it just appears to be the `listings` which is being awkward.

```latex
\documentclass[english,a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}  %% The ordering matters here. 
\usepackage{listings} %% The ordering matters here. 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{todonotes}

% List of Algorithms (NB, requires french spelling of 'algorithmes')
\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of algorithms}
\newcommand{\listofalgorithmes}{\tocfile{\listalgorithmcfname}{loa}}

% Suppose we want big paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip} 

% We want the list of listings to look like all the others. 
\let\Chapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\Chapter}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{\typeout{Chapters patched for list-of-listings.}}{\typeout{Could not patch chapters for list-of-listings.}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
% All the possible list of somethings I can think of and use. 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithmes
\listoftodos    

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}\section{Section}\section{Section}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}\section{Section}\section{Section}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\begin{table}[htb]\caption{A table}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[htb]\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code}]
\end{lstlisting}
\todo[inline=true,caption={A todo note}]{Must do this.}
\begin{algorithm}[htb] \DontPrintSemicolon \KwIn{Input} \KwOut{Output} Code\; \caption{Some algorithm.} \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: listings contains a `\@ifundefined{float@listhead}` part. This means that if it detects the float package it redefines \listoflistings and there set the parskip to 0pt.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, so if I had been unable/unwilling to sacrifice alphabetic ordering of packages, would there be a way to make listings respect the local value of \parskip? Perhaps something in the preamble after `\usepackage{listings}` and before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: `\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lstlistoflistings{\parskip\z@}{\parskip\baselineskip}{}{\fail}
\makeatother`